# Help with pseudorandom functions

Tags: pseudo-random-function

I started a new lecture this year about crypto and I've had a few problems in the first few weeks with the exercises we got.

I would appreciate a "guide" on how to solve problems like the following one because I feel like it will haunt me later in the semester if I don't figure it out now. Please don't simply post a solution, I need to figure this one out myself.

> Let $F : \{0, 1\}^n × \{0, 1\}^n → \{0, 1\}^n$ be a pseudorandom function. Prove or disprove that this is also a secure pseudorandom function:
>   $$F'(x) := F(x ⊕ 1^n)$$

Comment: Don't you have a textbook? Lecture notes? Have you not seen some such problems in class?

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Does it simplify the problem for you if you omit n? (or only consider the n=1 case)
2. Suppose F(x⊕1<sup>n</sup>) would *not* be a pseudorandom function, what does that tell you about the pseudorandomness of the original function F?